# Add edge such that resulting graph is 2-degenerate

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

I'm preparing for an exams and I can't find out how to solve this kind of examples.

The question is, whether it is possible to add two new edges into the graph such that the resulting graph is 2-degenerate and prove it.

[image]

Can't figure out anything.

Any hint would be appreciated. The best would be some rules.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following graph is $2$-degenerate, suppose it had a subgraph $\mathcal H$  with no vertex of degree $2$ or less. Then $\mathcal H$ would not contain $A$ or $H$.

[image]

So $\mathcal H$ would be a subgraph of the following graph:

[image]

We can now deduce that $\mathcal H$ would also not contain $B$ or $G$, so it would be a subgraph of the following graph:

[image]

And it should be clear that every subgraph of this graph has a vertex with degree $2$ or less.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This seems to be correct. But I've tried to apply your proof (or way) to decide whether another graph is $2$-degenerate and it seems that it does not work on this example - I've added two edges. Instead of E-F and D-E, I've added B-D and E-H. I think that this graph is $2$-degenerate too, but I can't keep removing vertexes with degree 2 after removing A vertex. Could you help me with this case?

Comment: If you add $B-D$ and $E-H$ it wont work because in the induced subgraph with vertices $B,C,E,D,F$ all of the vertices have degree $3$ or more. In other words, this graph is not $2$-degenerate.

Comment: It's not true. E would have degree one in that case. I've added those edges into original graph, not to the graph you've created.

Comment: http://sketchtoy.com/66531279 Here is the graph.

Comment: But then the induced subgraph on all vertices except $A$ has no vertex with degree $2$ or less right?

Comment: I'm retarded, sorry :) Thanks!